# Find max sum of elements in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Write a program which by given array of integer values (containing negative integers) finds the maximum sum of successive elements in the array.

Example:

> 2, 3, -6, -1, **2, -1, 6, 4**, -8, 8

Gives

> 11

I am searching for a solution which is faster than O(N^2).

Comment: 1,2,5,6 are not successive. If you have no restriction on the subset that can be taken, this is the Subset-Sum problem, which is NP-Complete, but I don't think it is the case.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have made a mistake in the description and example. :) I have updated both.

Comment: A linear scan can solve this problem. Just sum up and compare with current max, if the sum < 0, then reset sum to 0 and continue. This greedy solution has been proven to be correct. It's called Kadane's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @user1106337: It works for any case - even if the whole array is negative (just pick the largest of all negative numbers).

Comment: @jjm: No, this is not subset sum.

Comment: @jjm: Read the edit, it is not subset sum problem - because you are not free to chose any subset you want, you are choosing a sub-array. There are `n*(n-1)` different possibilities to do so, so the problem is definetly not NPC. (Before the edit - the example indeed showed the subset-sum problem)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [Kadane's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) is what you want

Comment: link is no longer valid

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a textbook problem I studied in college(Data Structures and Algorithms in C by Mark Allen Weiss)...It is a very beautiful and elegant solution and solves in O(N)

```
int MaxSubsequenceSum(int A[])
{
    int sum = 0, maxSum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < A.Length; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + A[j];

        if (sum > maxSum)
            maxSum = sum ;
        else if (sum < 0)
            sum = 0;
    }
    return maxSum;
}
```

Comment: Your post was edited by an anonymous user and then approved. Could you confirm that these changes are, in fact, positive? It seemed to change the logic significantly.

Comment: no I didnt approve it & it does not significantly improve the answer either. I think it was done for points

Comment: Was done by an anonymous user, so no rep was awarded. Feel free to roll back. They [left a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12339772/revisions) about why they did it.

Comment: `sum = maxSum + A[j];` is wrong. I'm reverting it (after 2, 3, -6, -1, 2, the sum becomes 7 when it should be 2)

Answer (score -3):

You can first sort the given array in descending order and then sum up the first three elements of the array by :
`sum=arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2]`
by intializing the `sum=0` and print sum.