# Maximal sum of submatrix NxN matrix and with N-nonzero values, only O(N^2)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, submatrix

Suppose you have an N × N matrix where each row has exactly one nonzero element and each column has exactly one nonzero element (the nonzero elements can be either positive or negative). We want to find the maximum-sum submatrix. How efficiently can we do so?

The matrix has dimension N × N and only N non-zero elements. N is so big, so I can't use an O(N<sup>3</sup>) algorithm. Does anyone know how to solve this in time O(N<sup>2</sup>), O(N log N), or some other time complexity like this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the "trivial situation"?

Comment: I'm assuming that the location of the N non-zero elements is unknown (not a sparse matrix) and the values are both positive and negative?

Comment: If you're not using a sparse matrix then O(N^2) is the best you can possibly do, since you at least have to read every element. There's probably some generalization of Kadane's Algorithm into two dimensions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339280/find-max-sum-of-elements-in-array

Comment: O(N^3) with Kadane's in 2D. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-27-max-sum-rectangle-in-a-2d-matrix/

Comment: If each column has exactly one nonzero element, then you can collapse the matrix into an array and apply Kadane's algorithm with O(N) complexity. But since you still probably have to go through all elements (in order to find those nonzeros) you obtain O(N^2) as @Adam noticed.

Comment: @freakish not so, because a submatrix does not necessarily collapse to a contiguous subvector of the collapsed array.

Comment: @BrianBi Of course it does. You can just consider submatrices composed of whole columns.

Comment: @freakish take the submatrix consisting of the first two rows:
XOO
OOX
OXO

Comment: @BrianBi Ah, I see. Right, right.

Comment: @freakish how does this solve the problem? If you reorder the columns then submatrices are not mapped to submatrices.

Comment: @BrianBi Yep, you're right. I guess there are no shortcuts.

Comment: How is the matrix stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the maximum sum subrectangle, you can do it in O(n^2 log n) time using the algorithm described here [maximum sum subrectangle in a sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558028/maximum-sum-subrectangle-in-a-sparse-matrix) . This beats Kadane's algorithm which is O(n^3).